# MVC4 modificar un parametro del modelo de una vista parcial, desde otro controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Favor si alguien podría ayudarme a modificar el valor de la propiedad de un modelo de una vista parcial.
El problema es el siguiente tengo el la vista A que invoca a la vista parcial A1.

Llamo a la parcial     `@Html.Action("Child", "Token")`

en el controlador de quien lo llama intento modificar una propiedad del modelo de la vista parcial

```
   public ActionResult FinTransacc(Object Aux) {

                if (Aux.token != "999999")
                {
                    Aux.mensaje = "Es invalido";
                    return View("Confirmacion", Aux);
                }
            }
```

pero al llegar al controlador de la vista parcial esa asignacion   Aux.mensaje = "Es invalido"; siempre llega null.

Como podria modificar ese valor de la propiedad del modelo de la vista parcial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno amigo tu pregunta esta algo confusa parece que lo que pretendes es mandar un mensaje. Podrías usar [ViewData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewdata(v=vs.118).aspx), [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) o [TempData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx) para pasar mensajes entre vistas o controladores revisa la documentación de estos.

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.

Comment: es una solucion el usar el tempdata, sin embargo lo que buscaba es poder modificar la informacion que viene del request hacia el controlador de la vista parcial, no se si con un filter se puede hacer ello.